# Download pictures from skydrive.live.com without creating a user?

Tags: office-365, onedrive

A relative sent some pictures to my parents, using some skydrive.live.com service to store them. Of course Microsoft tries "recruit" new users when they have a chance...

Is there any way to download those pictures without being forced to create a user account?

Comment: First answer does not seem to understand the question--they, and I, want to download the pics to our own computer that our family member uploaded to skydrive.live.com.  The usual right-click context menu method does not work, possibly due to the silverlight method that Microsoft is using to display the pics and run a slideshow of them presumably streamed to us rather than running it on our computer, although I don't really know that for sure.  In any event, the point is to get the pics on our computer so we can print them or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they can view them. It's no problem for Office documents, which can be opened directly in SkyDrive (now OneDrive), or images you want to see. But you can't send a link to the file and download it. When you need to download them, you need to have a Live ID.

Comment: It is some time ago, but as far as I remember this was resolved by asking them to resend in some other way, since Microsoft (probably deliberately) does not provide any means to download without any userid.

Answer (score 2):

You have the option to create a URL that does not require an account. Just send that and they can access it based on the security that applies.

It would look like this when you go to share:

> Share with everyone
>   Copy this link to share:

Note: Anyone can use this link to view the item without signing in to Windows Live.